# IOException:connection reset. This is repeating very frequently in my application in HttpClient.exeute()

Tags: spring, apache, httpclient

I have a scenario in application where I will make HttpClient.execute method to get a resource.

I found that when accessing application , I am not finding that resource and when I see logs I can see frequent logging of exception

2013-06-07 07:38:57,924, ERROR, , com.myapp.HTTPCall - HTTPCall.makeHttpCall :: IOException :: Connection reset
2013-06-07 07:38:57,954, ERROR, , com.myapp.HTTPCall - HTTPCall.makeHttpCall :: IOException :: Connection reset
2013-06-07 07:38:57,984, ERROR, , com.myapp.HTTPCall - HTTPCall.makeHttpCall :: IOException :: Connection reset
2013-06-07 07:38:58,014, ERROR, , com.myapp.HTTPCall - HTTPCall.makeHttpCall :: IOException :: Connection reset
2013-06-07 07:38:58,044, ERROR, , com.myapp.HTTPCall - HTTPCall.makeHttpCall :: IOException :: Connection reset
2013-06-07 07:38:58,074, ERROR, , com.myapp.HTTPCall - HTTPCall.makeHttpCall :: IOException :: Connection reset

This is repeating every second. What might be the issue?the requested resource is in apache webserver.

Comment: If your not finding the resource, have you checked the URL you are requesting to make sure it's valid?  Does it work in a browser?  can you ping the server you are trying to get to from the server you are running your app on?  Can you get to the Apache logs on the remote server and see your request come it?  What is in the logs?

Comment: Resource is there . Also Im facing this issue intermittently.

Comment: Why is this error so frequent? One error per 30ms is a lot of errors. Are you calling it a cycle? What do the access and error logs of your apache say? What does your operating system log say (*too many opened files* and stuff like that)? Have you tried to sniff the communication?

Comment: If you are using keep-alive, try switching it off.

Comment: When you say switch off keep alive ,is it Apache side???

Comment: Yes, Apache has its own directives for configuring keep-alive. The client can also disable keep-alive by sending the Connection: close header.